# Problem with VertexCoordinates in Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to plot a graph introducing some coordinates that I previously imported from Excel. The function graph receive vertex,edges and coordinates as you can see in the image below. The reason I add the set vertex is cz the order of coordinates is the same that vertex. Otherwise, the coordinates are assumed to follow the order of VertexList[Edges], which is not correct.

[image: MainCode]

I get the graph as I want, but with the following message: "Coordinate {Indeterminate, DirectedInfinity[]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.". (See image above)

What I have tried so far:

1. Deleted the set of vertices, that eliminates the error, but the graph is a mess! A nest!
2. Created a new list of coordinates were each element using Scaled[], for example: `vertex={Scaled[198,144],Scaled[101,155],... }`. Btw, using the other parameter of Scaled did not help neither(`vertex={Scaled[{1,1},{198,144}],Scaled[{1,1},{101,155}],... }`).
3. Same than before but instead of `Scaled`, `Offset`. I.e: `vertex=OffSet[{198,144}],OffSet[{101,155}],... }`.
4. Same than 3 but using ImageScaled.
5. I also, unsuccessfully, tried using `Property->` and `Properties->` in the function `Graph`.

The function is given by:

```
NetworkPlot[C_, E_] := Module[{Edges, Vertx, Coord}, (
  Coord = IntegerPart[C[[All, 2 ;; 3]]];
  Edges = E;
  Vertx = C[[All, 1]];
  NwIdl = Graph[Vertx, Edges,
  VertexCoordinates -> Coord
  ]
)];
NetworkPlot[Coord, Edges]
```

If you generate your own data and it does work, please try with this data:

```
Coord = {{"OD401", 182.`, 174.`}, {"OD402", 183.`, 153.`}, {"OD403", 
    192.`, 194.`}, {"OD411", 116.`, 206.`}, {"OD40", 191.`, 
    188.`}, {"OD42", 173.`, 182.`}, {"OD43", 178.`, 187.`}, {"OD45", 
    177.`, 202.`}, {"OD47", 167.`, 195.`}, {"OD48", 165.`, 
    204.`}, {"OD123", 160.`, 164.`}, {"OD125", 131.`, 
    131.`}, {"OD128", 104.`, 159.`}, {"OD129", 125.`, 
    163.`}, {"OD130", 135.`, 143.`}, {"OD131", 170.`, 
    172.`}, {"OD132", 158.`, 169.`}, {"OD133", 146.`, 
    168.`}, {"OD134", 121.`, 189.`}, {"OD137", 117.`, 
    179.`}, {"OD138", 96.`, 175.`}, {"OD139", 81.`, 175.`}, {"OD141", 
    76.`, 191.`}, {"OD142", 112.`, 187.`}, {"OD175", 187.`, 
    200.`}, {"OD331", 185.`, 224.`}, {"OD404", 188.`, 
    182.`}, {"OD405", 194.`, 200.`}, {"OD406", 196.`, 
    205.`}, {"OD407", 191.`, 209.`}, {"OD408", 144.`, 
    208.`}, {"OD409", 139.`, 206.`}, {"OD410", 100.`, 
    211.`}, {"OD412", 90.`, 206.`}, {"OD413", 64.`, 140.`}, {"OD414", 
    70.`, 204.`}, {"OD415", 112.`, 130.`}, {"OD416", 90.`, 
    135.`}, {"OD417", 130.`, 113.`}, {"OD418", 147.`, 
    122.`}, {"JNC401J", 190.`, 197.`}, {"JNC402J", 183.`, 
    191.`}, {"JNC403J", 186.`, 182.`}, {"JNC411J", 181.`, 
    174.`}, {"JNC392", 188.`, 200.`}, {"JNC393", 194.`, 
    200.`}, {"JNC421", 175.`, 178.`}, {"JNC422", 176.`, 
    185.`}, {"JNC423", 176.`, 181.`}, {"JNC431", 172.`, 
    190.`}, {"JNC432", 177.`, 183.`}, {"JNC433", 181.`, 
    187.`}, {"JNC434", 182.`, 190.`}, {"JNC461", 190.`, 
    208.`}, {"JNC471", 162.`, 192.`}, {"JNC481", 154.`, 
    196.`}, {"JNC484", 144.`, 207.`}, {"JNC486", 156.`, 
    195.`}, {"JNC487", 161.`, 200.`}, {"JNC1212", 181.`, 
    154.`}, {"JNC1215", 172.`, 174.`}, {"JNC1231", 169.`, 
    170.`}, {"JNC1232", 161.`, 152.`}, {"JNC1233", 154.`, 
    140.`}, {"JNC1243", 147.`, 124.`}, {"JNC1251", 138.`, 
    142.`}, {"JNC1252", 133.`, 144.`}, {"JNC1253", 126.`, 
    149.`}, {"JNC1254", 122.`, 138.`}, {"JNC1255", 124.`, 
    131.`}, {"JNC1256", 130.`, 115.`}, {"JNC1257", 134.`, 
    140.`}, {"JNC1258", 136.`, 142.`}, {"JNC1261", 113.`, 
    131.`}, {"JNC1269", 65.`, 140.`}, {"JNC1281", 80.`, 
    152.`}, {"JNC1282", 92.`, 148.`}, {"JNC1283", 100.`, 
    148.`}, {"JNC1284", 110.`, 150.`}, {"JNC1285", 92.`, 
    140.`}, {"JNC1286", 91.`, 125.`}, {"JNC1291", 119.`, 
    171.`}, {"JNC1292", 111.`, 167.`}, {"JNC1293", 114.`, 
    163.`}, {"JNC1294", 120.`, 155.`}, {"JNC1321", 158.`, 
    182.`}, {"JNC1331", 147.`, 182.`}, {"JNC1332", 144.`, 
    182.`}, {"JNC1341", 146.`, 196.`}, {"JNC1342", 138.`, 
    196.`}, {"JNC1343", 135.`, 196.`}, {"JNC1344", 130.`, 
    189.`}, {"JNC1351", 139.`, 205.`}, {"JNC1371", 120.`, 
    183.`}, {"JNC1372", 115.`, 175.`}, {"JNC1373", 120.`, 
    177.`}, {"JNC1374", 123.`, 178.`}, {"JNC1375", 129.`, 
    180.`}, {"JNC1376", 107.`, 173.`}, {"JNC1381", 106.`, 
    174.`}, {"JNC1382", 98.`, 168.`}, {"JNC1383", 101.`, 
    181.`}, {"JNC1384", 91.`, 184.`}, {"JNC1385", 99.`, 
    186.`}, {"JNC1391", 89.`, 178.`}, {"JNC1392", 89.`, 
    163.`}, {"JNC1393", 84.`, 160.`}, {"JNC1404", 71.`, 
    203.`}, {"JNC1411", 91.`, 194.`}, {"JNC1412", 91.`, 
    199.`}, {"JNC1413", 97.`, 196.`}, {"JNC1414", 98.`, 
    196.`}, {"JNC1415", 98.`, 189.`}, {"JNC1416", 90.`, 
    187.`}, {"JNC1417", 82.`, 189.`}, {"JNC1418", 88.`, 
    192.`}, {"JNC1422", 106.`, 193.`}, {"JNC1423", 111.`, 
    195.`}, {"JNC1424", 118.`, 197.`}, {"JNC1425", 109.`, 
    190.`}, {"JNC1426", 112.`, 192.`}, {"JNC1427", 114.`, 
    193.`}, {"JNC1431", 117.`, 205.`}, {"JNC1451", 91.`, 
    205.`}, {"JNC1466", 102.`, 210.`}, {"JNC4211", 173.`, 
    180.`}, {"JNC4221", 173.`, 184.`}, {"JNC9821", 181.`, 
    203.`}, {"JNC9918", 191.`, 193.`}, {"JNC9920", 195.`, 
    204.`}, {"JNC9921", 184.`, 203.`}, {"JNC9927", 187.`, 
    206.`}, {"JNC9928", 185.`, 193.`}, {"JNC12311", 167.`, 
    171.`}, {"JNC12831", 102.`, 153.`}, {"JNC12911", 121.`, 
    168.`}, {"JNC12931", 110.`, 165.`}, {"JNC12941", 121.`, 
    154.`}, {"JNC13211", 160.`, 176.`}, {"JNC13311", 146.`, 
    176.`}, {"JNC13441", 127.`, 190.`}, {"JNC13711", 118.`, 
    181.`}, {"JNC13721", 116.`, 178.`}, {"JNC13821", 97.`, 
    171.`}, {"JNC13831", 98.`, 178.`}, {"JNC13841", 98.`, 
    187.`}, {"JNC13911", 85.`, 178.`}, {"JNC13921", 85.`, 
    165.`}, {"JNC14111", 83.`, 192.`}, {"JNC14251", 108.`, 187.`}};


Edges = {"JNC393" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC392", 
   "JNC401J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC392", 
   "JNC9920" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC392", 
   "JNC392" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC393", 
   "JNC392" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC401J", 
   "JNC9918" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC401J", 
   "JNC9921" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC401J", 
   "JNC9928" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC401J", 
   "JNC431" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC402J", 
   "JNC434" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC402J", 
   "JNC9928" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC402J", 
   "JNC433" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC403J", 
   "JNC432" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC411J", 
   "JNC423" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC421", 
   "JNC1215" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC421", 
   "JNC4211" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC421", 
   "JNC431" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC422", 
   "JNC432" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC422", 
   "JNC4221" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC422", 
   "JNC421" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC423", 
   "JNC432" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC423", 
   "JNC1231" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC423", 
   "JNC402J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC431", 
   "JNC422" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC431", 
   "JNC471" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC431", 
   "JNC411J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC432", 
   "JNC422" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC432", 
   "JNC423" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC432", 
   "JNC433" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC432", 
   "JNC403J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC433", 
   "JNC432" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC433", 
   "JNC434" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC433", 
   "JNC402J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC434", 
   "JNC432" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC434", 
   "JNC433" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC434", 
   "JNC9927" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC461", 
   "JNC431" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC471", 
   "JNC486" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC471", 
   "JNC1321" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC471", 
   "JNC484" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC481", 
   "JNC486" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC481", 
   "JNC1341" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC481", 
   "JNC481" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC484", 
   "JNC471" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC486", 
   "JNC481" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC486", 
   "JNC487" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC486", 
   "JNC486" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC487", 
   "JNC1215" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1212", 
   "JNC421" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1215", 
   "JNC1212" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1215", 
   "JNC1231" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1215", 
   "JNC1215" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1231", 
   "JNC1232" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1231", 
   "JNC12311" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1231", 
   "JNC1231" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1232", 
   "JNC1233" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1232", 
   "JNC1232" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1233", 
   "JNC1243" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1233", 
   "JNC1251" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1233", 
   "JNC1233" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1243", 
   "JNC1233" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1251", 
   "JNC1252" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1251", 
   "JNC1258" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1251", 
   "JNC1251" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1252", 
   "JNC1253" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1252", 
   "JNC1257" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1252", 
   "JNC1252" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1253", 
   "JNC1254" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1253", 
   "JNC12941" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1253", 
   "JNC1253" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1254", 
   "JNC1255" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1254", 
   "JNC1254" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1255", 
   "JNC1256" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1255", 
   "JNC1257" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1255", 
   "JNC1261" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1255", 
   "JNC1255" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1256", 
   "JNC1251" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1257", 
   "JNC1252" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1257", 
   "JNC1255" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1257", 
   "JNC1251" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1258", 
   "JNC1255" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1261", 
   "JNC1281" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1269", 
   "JNC1269" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1281", 
   "JNC1282" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1281", 
   "JNC1393" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1281", 
   "JNC1281" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1282", 
   "JNC1283" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1282", 
   "JNC1285" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1282", 
   "JNC1282" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1283", 
   "JNC1284" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1283", 
   "JNC12831" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1283", 
   "JNC1283" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1284", 
   "JNC1285" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1284", 
   "JNC1294" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1284", 
   "JNC1282" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1285", 
   "JNC1284" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1285", 
   "JNC1286" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1285", 
   "JNC1285" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1286", 
   "JNC1292" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1291", 
   "JNC1373" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1291", 
   "JNC12911" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1291", 
   "JNC1291" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1292", 
   "JNC1293" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1292", 
   "JNC1376" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1292", 
   "JNC1292" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1293", 
   "JNC1294" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1293", 
   "JNC12931" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1293", 
   "JNC1284" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1294", 
   "JNC1293" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1294", 
   "JNC12941" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1294", 
   "JNC471" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1321", 
   "JNC1331" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1321", 
   "JNC13211" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1321", 
   "JNC1321" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1331", 
   "JNC1332" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1331", 
   "JNC13311" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1331", 
   "JNC1331" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1332", 
   "JNC1341" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1332", 
   "JNC1375" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1332", 
   "JNC481" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1341", 
   "JNC1332" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1341", 
   "JNC1342" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1341", 
   "JNC1341" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1342", 
   "JNC1343" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1342", 
   "JNC1351" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1342", 
   "JNC1342" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1343", 
   "JNC1344" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1343", 
   "JNC1424" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1343", 
   "JNC1343" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1344", 
   "JNC1375" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1344", 
   "JNC13441" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1344", 
   "JNC1342" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1351", 
   "JNC1374" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1371", 
   "JNC1427" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1371", 
   "JNC13711" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1371", 
   "JNC1373" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1372", 
   "JNC1376" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1372", 
   "JNC13721" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1372", 
   "JNC1291" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1373", 
   "JNC1372" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1373", 
   "JNC1374" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1373", 
   "JNC1371" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1374", 
   "JNC1373" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1374", 
   "JNC1375" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1374", 
   "JNC1332" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1375", 
   "JNC1344" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1375", 
   "JNC1374" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1375", 
   "JNC1292" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1376", 
   "JNC1372" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1376", 
   "JNC1381" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1376", 
   "JNC1376" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1381", 
   "JNC1382" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1381", 
   "JNC1383" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1381", 
   "JNC1381" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1382", 
   "JNC1393" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1382", 
   "JNC13821" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1382", 
   "JNC1381" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1383", 
   "JNC1385" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1383", 
   "JNC13831" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1383", 
   "JNC1391" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1384", 
   "JNC1416" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1384", 
   "JNC13841" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1384", 
   "JNC1383" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1385", 
   "JNC1425" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1385", 
   "JNC13841" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1385", 
   "JNC1384" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1391", 
   "JNC1392" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1391", 
   "JNC13911" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1391", 
   "JNC1391" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1392", 
   "JNC1393" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1392", 
   "JNC13921" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1392", 
   "JNC1281" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1393", 
   "JNC1382" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1393", 
   "JNC1392" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1393", 
   "JNC1412" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1404", 
   "JNC1412" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1411", 
   "JNC1416" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1411", 
   "JNC1418" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1411", 
   "JNC1404" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1412", 
   "JNC1411" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1412", 
   "JNC1413" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1412", 
   "JNC1451" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1412", 
   "JNC1412" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1413", 
   "JNC1414" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1413", 
   "JNC1466" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1413", 
   "JNC1413" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1414", 
   "JNC1415" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1414", 
   "JNC1422" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1414", 
   "JNC1414" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1415", 
   "JNC1422" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1415", 
   "JNC13841" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1415", 
   "JNC1384" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1416", 
   "JNC1411" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1416", 
   "JNC1417" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1416", 
   "JNC1416" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1417", 
   "JNC1418" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1417", 
   "JNC14111" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1417", 
   "JNC1411" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1418", 
   "JNC1417" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1418", 
   "JNC1414" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1422", 
   "JNC1415" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1422", 
   "JNC1423" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1422", 
   "JNC1422" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1423", 
   "JNC1424" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1423", 
   "JNC1426" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1423", 
   "JNC1343" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1424", 
   "JNC1423" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1424", 
   "JNC1431" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1424", 
   "JNC1385" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1425", 
   "JNC1426" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1425", 
   "JNC14251" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1425", 
   "JNC1423" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1426", 
   "JNC1425" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1426", 
   "JNC1427" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1426", 
   "JNC1371" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1427", 
   "JNC1426" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1427", 
   "JNC1424" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1431", 
   "JNC1412" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1451", 
   "JNC1413" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1466", 
   "JNC421" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC4211", 
   "JNC422" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC4221", 
   "JNC9921" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9821", 
   "JNC401J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9918", 
   "JNC392" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9920", 
   "JNC401J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9921", 
   "JNC9821" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9921", 
   "JNC9927" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9921", 
   "JNC461" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9927", 
   "JNC9921" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9927", 
   "JNC401J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9928", 
   "JNC402J" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9928", 
   "JNC1231" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12311", 
   "JNC1283" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12831", 
   "JNC1291" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12911", 
   "JNC1293" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12931", 
   "JNC1253" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12941", 
   "JNC1294" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12941", 
   "JNC1321" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13211", 
   "JNC1331" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13311", 
   "JNC1344" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13441", 
   "JNC1371" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13711", 
   "JNC1372" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13721", 
   "JNC1382" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13821", 
   "JNC1383" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13831", 
   "JNC1384" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13841", 
   "JNC1385" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13841", 
   "JNC1415" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13841", 
   "JNC1391" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13911", 
   "JNC1392" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13921", 
   "JNC1417" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC14111", 
   "JNC1425" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC14251", 
   "OD401" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC411J", 
   "OD402" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1212", 
   "OD403" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9918", 
   "OD411" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1431", 
   "OD40" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC402J", "OD40" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9928",
    "OD42" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC4221", 
   "OD42" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC4211", "OD43" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC431", 
   "OD43" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC432", "OD43" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC433", 
   "OD43" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC402J", "OD45" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9821",
    "OD47" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC471", "OD47" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC431", 
   "OD48" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC487", "OD123" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1231",
    "OD123" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1232", 
   "OD125" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1254", 
   "OD125" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1255", 
   "OD125" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1256", 
   "OD128" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12831", 
   "OD129" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12911", 
   "OD129" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12931", 
   "OD130" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1258", 
   "OD131" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC12311", 
   "OD132" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13211", 
   "OD133" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13311", 
   "OD134" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13441", 
   "OD137" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13711", 
   "OD137" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13721", 
   "OD138" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1383", 
   "OD138" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13821", 
   "OD139" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13911", 
   "OD139" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC13921", 
   "OD141" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC14111", 
   "OD142" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC14251", 
   "OD175" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9921", 
   "OD175" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC401J", 
   "OD331" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9821", 
   "OD404" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC403J", 
   "OD405" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC393", 
   "OD406" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC9920", 
   "OD407" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC461", "OD408" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC484",
    "OD409" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1351", 
   "OD410" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1466", 
   "OD412" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1451", 
   "OD413" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1269", 
   "OD414" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1404", 
   "OD415" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1261", 
   "OD416" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1286", 
   "OD417" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1256", 
   "OD418" \[DirectedEdge] "JNC1243", 
   "JNC411J" \[DirectedEdge] "OD401", 
   "JNC1212" \[DirectedEdge] "OD402", 
   "JNC9918" \[DirectedEdge] "OD403", 
   "JNC1431" \[DirectedEdge] "OD411", 
   "JNC402J" \[DirectedEdge] "OD40", "JNC9928" \[DirectedEdge] "OD40",
    "JNC4221" \[DirectedEdge] "OD42", 
   "JNC4211" \[DirectedEdge] "OD42", "JNC431" \[DirectedEdge] "OD43", 
   "JNC432" \[DirectedEdge] "OD43", "JNC433" \[DirectedEdge] "OD43", 
   "JNC402J" \[DirectedEdge] "OD43", "JNC9821" \[DirectedEdge] "OD45",
    "JNC471" \[DirectedEdge] "OD47", "JNC431" \[DirectedEdge] "OD47", 
   "JNC487" \[DirectedEdge] "OD48", "JNC1231" \[DirectedEdge] "OD123",
    "JNC1232" \[DirectedEdge] "OD123", 
   "JNC1254" \[DirectedEdge] "OD125", 
   "JNC1255" \[DirectedEdge] "OD125", 
   "JNC1256" \[DirectedEdge] "OD125", 
   "JNC12831" \[DirectedEdge] "OD128", 
   "JNC12911" \[DirectedEdge] "OD129", 
   "JNC12931" \[DirectedEdge] "OD129", 
   "JNC1258" \[DirectedEdge] "OD130", 
   "JNC12311" \[DirectedEdge] "OD131", 
   "JNC13211" \[DirectedEdge] "OD132", 
   "JNC13311" \[DirectedEdge] "OD133", 
   "JNC13441" \[DirectedEdge] "OD134", 
   "JNC13711" \[DirectedEdge] "OD137", 
   "JNC13721" \[DirectedEdge] "OD137", 
   "JNC1383" \[DirectedEdge] "OD138", 
   "JNC13821" \[DirectedEdge] "OD138", 
   "JNC13911" \[DirectedEdge] "OD139", 
   "JNC13921" \[DirectedEdge] "OD139", 
   "JNC14111" \[DirectedEdge] "OD141", 
   "JNC14251" \[DirectedEdge] "OD142", 
   "JNC9921" \[DirectedEdge] "OD175", 
   "JNC401J" \[DirectedEdge] "OD175", 
   "JNC9821" \[DirectedEdge] "OD331", 
   "JNC403J" \[DirectedEdge] "OD404", 
   "JNC393" \[DirectedEdge] "OD405", 
   "JNC9920" \[DirectedEdge] "OD406", 
   "JNC461" \[DirectedEdge] "OD407", "JNC484" \[DirectedEdge] "OD408",
    "JNC1351" \[DirectedEdge] "OD409", 
   "JNC1466" \[DirectedEdge] "OD410", 
   "JNC1451" \[DirectedEdge] "OD412", 
   "JNC1269" \[DirectedEdge] "OD413", 
   "JNC1404" \[DirectedEdge] "OD414", 
   "JNC1261" \[DirectedEdge] "OD415", 
   "JNC1286" \[DirectedEdge] "OD416", 
   "JNC1256" \[DirectedEdge] "OD417", 
   "JNC1243" \[DirectedEdge] "OD418"};
```

Finally, how can I get rid of that annoying message?

Thanks people!

Comment: tested your set and it works fine to me (version v11.1 on mac)

Comment: Thanks @halmir. The message remain appearing to me. I am using the version 11.0. If anyone else can try it, that would be great.